# Unable to save dataType Timestamp to PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

i am trying to insert data to my PostgreSQL table, i am getting date as string from form, but i end up with this error

> ERROR: malformed array literal: "" LINE 2: ...d','2018-07-27 00:00:00','2018-07-27 00:00:00','','',1,1,'',... ^ DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

this is my query

```
insert into events (title,location,description,start_date,end_date,start_time,end_time,is_pet,is_child,untill,repeat) values ('test','asdasd','asdasd',2018-07-27 00:00:00,2018-07-27 00:00:00,'','',1,1,'','Does Not Repeat')
```

and my query is parsed like this

```
$query = "insert into events (title,location,description,start_date,end_date,start_time,end_time,is_pet,is_child,untill,repeat) values 
          ('$title','$location','$description',$start_date,$end_date,'$start_time','$end_time',$is_pet,$is_child,'$until','$repeat')";

$sql = pg_query($query);
if (!$sql) {
    echo pg_last_error($db);
} else {
    echo "Records created successfully\n";
}
```

My Schema as follows

```
CREATE TABLE public.events (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying(255),
    location character varying(255),
    description character varying(255),
    end_date timestamp without time zone,
    start_time character varying(20),
    end_time character varying(20)[],
    image character varying(500),
    is_pet boolean,
    is_child boolean,
    repeat character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    posted_by character varying(255),
    email character varying(255),
    untill date,
    start_date timestamp without time zone
);
```

Comment: In your table, `end_time` is an array. Presumably that's a mistake as it makes no sense. That's why PG is complaining, you're giving it something that is not an array and it's telling you an array must start with `{`

Comment: In your example query output, and sql string build... you appear to be missing the single quotes around the date strings. This may cause an issue. Try first to just add single quotes around `$start_date` and `$end_date`. However, a better solution would to do this with prepared statements, so that you don't have to worry about proper quoting and escaping of data in a sql query. Begin with [pg_prepare](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php).