# node & postgres - error: malformed array literal: timestamp

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using node and postgresql (and node-postgres).

I am trying to execute an insert statement, but I get the following error:

> error: malformed array literal: "2020-01-15T20:09:22.711+02:00"

My code is as follows:

```
const queryInsert = {
  text: 'INSERT INTO my_table(some_date, last_update) VALUES($1, $2)',
  values: [2020-01-15T20:09:22.711+02:00, new Date()]
}

  client.query(
    queryInsert.text,
    queryInsert.values,
    (err, res)=> {
      done();
      if (err) {
        console.log('Query: '+queryInsert.text, err);
      }
      console.log(res);
    }
  );
```

**Question**

Do I need to somehow format the values if they are dates? If so, how?  If not, any advise welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I have found a similar question here, but no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572256/unable-to-save-datatype-timestamp-to-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-postgres appears to only accept dates as actual Date objects, not as strings. [Documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/types#date%20/%20timestamp%20/%20timestamptz)

```js
const queryInsert = {
  text: 'INSERT INTO my_table(some_date, last_update) VALUES($1, $2)',
  values: [new Date("2020-01-15T20:09:22.711+02:00"), new Date()]
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried using `Date.parse(...)` as you suggect, but now I get the following error: `error: malformed array literal: "1555937640000"`.

Comment: Ack, sorry, wrong method. You want to use `new Date("…")` there, not `Date.parse()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: If I add `new Date('2019-05-04T08:00:00.000+02:00')` I get the following `error: malformed array literal: "2019-05-04T08:00:00.000+02:00"`.

Comment: This is strange, because even if I do the following, I get the error, which contradicts the documentation: `values: [new Date(]), new Date()]`.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you're not passing something like `{ values: [] }` as the second argument to `query` instead of the raw array?

Comment: My code example is above, I am just using `queryInsert.values`. I think that's correct?

Comment: I think so too; the only other thought I have is to confirm that the `some_date` column is actually a date type.

Comment: That might be it, it is currently a `timestamp without timezone`. Let me try change it. Will see what options I can change it to.

Comment: I changed the columns to type `timestamp with time zone`, and that fixed it. Thank you for your help!